# read.csv in a loop

Tags: r, read.table

I have four csv files and I would like to input them with a for loop. They are all of the same size and only differ by the file names. Right now I am doing it this way:

```
Kleinheubach_GKD <- read.csv("/path_to_file/Kleinheubach.csv", skip= 10, header = T, nrows= 61, sep = ";")
Schwabelweis_GKD <- read.csv("/path_to_file/Schwabelweis.csv", skip= 10, header = T, nrows= 61, sep = ";")
Landau_GKD <- read.csv("/path_to_file/Landau.csv", skip= 10, header = T, nrows= 61, sep = ";")
Passau_GKD <- read.csv("/path_to_file/Passau.csv", skip= 10, header = T, nrows= 61, sep = ";")
```

This does the job, but it is not really elegant, especially when working with a higher number of files.

So I would like to do it by using a loop or something that leads to the same result.
This is one way I tried which did not work out:

```
for (i in c("Kleinheubach", "Schwabelweis", "Landau", "Passau")) {
   assign(paste0(i,"_GKD"), read.csv(paste("/path_to_file/", i,".csv_, skip= 10, header = T, nrows= 61, sep = ";"", sep="")))
}
```

I am quite sure the problem is linked to the wrong usage of the quotes. They are needed for the `paste` command as well as for the file path. I tried different combinations of `""` and `''`, but did not find the right combination for this case yet.

Does anybody know the proper usage in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, the `paste` would be `paste0` and it should be closed `)`

```
paste0("/path_to_file/", i,".csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply. What about the last part: ```skip= 10, header = T, nrows= 61, sep = ";"```? That needs to be included somehow too.

Comment: @climdrag those are the arguments in `read.csv`, it would be after the closing bracket of `paste0`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `file.path` to construct the full file names and `lapply` to read the data in. Note that `read.csv` already sets `header = TRUE`, there is no need to repeat it.

```
filenames <- c("Kleinheubach", "Schwabelweis", "Landau", "Passau")

file.path("/path/to/file", filenames)
#[1] "/path/to/file/Kleinheubach" "/path/to/file/Schwabelweis"
#[3] "/path/to/file/Landau"       "/path/to/file/Passau"      

df_list <- lapply(file.path("/path/to/file", filenames), read.csv, skip= 10, nrows= 61, sep = ";")

names(df_list) <- paste(filenames, "GKD", sep = "_")
```

In order to have the data sets in the `.GlobalEnv`,

```
list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked too. The above answer keeps everything in data frames which make the further processing easier in this case.